# Google Charts Tools - Scatter and Table Combo Interaction, why unidirectional?

Tags: api, events, charts, google-visualization

This is my first question on stack overflow.  I made a google chart tools scatter chart/table combination that is based on their examples.  When I click a row in the table, the corresponding point in the scatter is selected (that's good).  But it is not working in reverse. I cannot select a point in the scatter and have it select the corresponding row in the table.  Does anyone know why this does not work as expected?  my code is provided below:

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart", "table"]});
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Age', 'Weight'],
          [ 8,      12],
      [ 4,      5.5],
      [ 11,     14],
      [ 4,      5],
      [ 3,      3.5],
      [ 6.5,    7],
      [ 6.5,    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Age vs. Weight comparison',
      hAxis: {title: 'Age', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
      vAxis: {title: 'Weight', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
      legend: 'none'
    };

    var chart = new    google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    table.draw(data);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
    table.setSelection(chart.getSelection());});

    google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', function() {
    chart.setSelection(table.getSelection());});

  }
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
    <div id="table_div" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `getSelection()` returns both the column and row for the scatter graph and just row for the table, there's a bit of a conflict. Turns out, if you just pass the row information from the scatter graph, you can indeed select the table row, you just need the following:

```
table.setSelection([{row: chart.getSelection()[0].row}]);
```

That takes the first item you've clicked on and passes an object with just row data.

Inspiration from [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/google-visualization-api@googlegroups.com/msg01654.html) and working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/GXp4e/2/).